# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT & PHP parsing

Tags: php, mysql

Sample table,

```
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| book_id | book_name                           | isbn_no     | cate_id | aut_id | pub_id | dt_of_pub  | pub_lang | no_page | book_price |
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| BK001   | Introduction to Electrodynamics     | 0000979001  | CA001   | AUT001 | P003   | 2001-05-08 | English  |     201 |      85.00 |
| BK002   | Understanding of Steel Construction | 0000979002  | CA002   | AUT002 | P001   | 2003-07-15 | English  |     300 |     105.50 |
| BK003   | Guide to Networking                 | 0000979003  | CA003   | AUT003 | P002   | 2002-09-10 | Hindi    |     510 |     200.00 |
| BK004   | Transfer  of Heat and Mass          | 0000979004  | CA002   | AUT004 | P004   | 2004-02-16 | English  |     600 |     250.00 |
| BK005   | Conceptual Physics                  | 0000979005  | CA001   | AUT005 | P006   | 2003-07-16 | NULL     |     345 |     145.00 |
| BK006   | Fundamentals of Heat                | 0000979006  | CA001   | AUT006 | P005   | 2003-08-10 | German   |     247 |     112.00 |
| BK007   | Advanced 3d Graphics                | 0000979007  | CA003   | AUT007 | P002   | 2004-02-16 | Hindi    |     165 |      56.00 |
| BK008   | Human Anatomy                       | 0000979008  | CA005   | AUT008 | P006   | 2001-05-17 | German   |      88 |      50.50 |
| BK009   | Mental Health Nursing               | 0000979009  | CA005   | AUT009 | P007   | 2004-02-10 | English  |     350 |     145.00 |
| BK010   | Fundamentals of Thermodynamics      | 0000979010  | CA002   | AUT010 | P007   | 2002-10-14 | English  |     400 |     225.00 |
| BK011   | The Experimental Analysis of Cat    | 0000979011  | CA004   | AUT011 | P005   | 2007-06-09 | French   |     225 |      95.00 |
| BK012   | The Nature  of World                | 0000979012  | CA004   | AUT005 | P008   | 2005-12-20 | English  |     350 |      88.00 |
| BK013   | Environment a Sustainable Future    | 0000979013  | CA004   | AUT012 | P001   | 2003-10-27 | German   |     165 |     100.00 |
| BK014   | Concepts in Health                  | 0000979014  | CA005   | AUT013 | P004   | 2001-08-25 | NULL     |     320 |     180.00 |
| BK015   | Anatomy & Physiology                | 0000979015  | CA005   | AUT014 | P008   | 2000-10-10 | Hindi    |     225 |     135.00 |
| BK016   | Networks and Telecommunications     | 00009790_16 | CA003   | AUT015 | P003   | 2002-01-01 | French   |      95 |      45.00 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+------------+----------+---------+------------+
```

Outputs

```
mysql> SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(CATE_ID)
    -> FROM book_mast
    -> GROUP BY pub_id;
+--------+-----------------------+
| pub_id | GROUP_CONCAT(CATE_ID) |
+--------+-----------------------+
| P001   | CA002,CA004           | 
| P002   | CA003,CA003           | 
| P003   | CA001,CA003           | 
| P004   | CA005,CA002           | 
| P005   | CA001,CA004           | 
| P006   | CA005,CA001           | 
| P007   | CA005,CA002           | 
| P008   | CA005,CA004           | 
+--------+-----------------------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

And we can do this with PHP,

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(cate_id)  
FROM book_mast  
GROUP BY pub_id') as $row) {  
  //Use $row['GROUP_CONCAT(cate_id)'] 
}
```

**Now, if I want to parse more details about cate_id = Category ID, should I execute another query inside this foreach loop? Since I get the IDs of the categories.**

Comment: Could be mistaken, but it sounds like what you're after is table joins.

Comment: I have many joins in my query already. The point is, this isn't so much about LEFT JOIN or the other types of JOINS. Since I want to group certain results, using GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: @JonStirling, let me give you a hint, lets say you group certain items by a user_id. Now two IDs, here represent the two items, however, since we GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP_BY, we will only see the last result, so the other will appear in the [collection], as IDs, including the last one. Now in order for us to grab more data about each item, we need to query and parse again, do you see the big picture now?

Comment: You can't ask questions about performance without any data whatsoever. Is it expensive for PHP to "talk" to MySQL - no, it isn't, especially if you use `php-fpm` - it's super cheap to query MySQL. Is it expensive for MySQL to look for info in its dataset - it depends on size of the data and whether indexing can be used for retrieval (and whether you need lots of records back or not). Is PHP going to parse a few records or a billion records? These are the questions you need to ask yourself.  Your question can't be answered accurately, there are too many "what if" scenarios.

Comment: Swapping to preferred way of serving PHP would yield tenfold performance. At best, you are microoptimizing here, I doubt you have billion-record dataset. Repeating two relatively cheap queries isn't that problematic nor is it something that you should even bother optimizing (at least I wouldn't, but we're all different). Also parsing a few records in PHP isn't slow, so your question boils down more to preferred way of doing this instead of performance - and the answer is - whatever you find easier to maintain is what you're after.

Comment: Seriously, sure, I do not have 1 million (or billion) records. The question, does boil down to performance, however, it is also related to this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31515/group-activities-in-activity-feed-by-users-and-products, in some way. Hope that link clears it all.

Comment: The less you do, the faster it is. Can you get all relevant info in a single MySQL query? If yes, and if you don't have too many records then it's more performant to issue 1 query and parse the results in PHP. Parsing an array with a few thousand records is always faster than MySQL<>PHP roundtrip.

Comment: @Mjh did you see the link I posted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion it's not good practice to use two queries we can get data from multiple tables using join query or by creating Alias of table name it would be better if you use direct one query.

Note: the sql inner query should have different table name like this

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts where ID in(select ID from abc)
```

For the same table you can make dynamic query using php condition.